# Rationale of __instancecheck__ on protocols

Tags: protocols, python-typing, python-3.9

Below is the complete source code of the class `_ProtocolMeta` [used as metaclass](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/typing.py#L1116) for `typing.Protocol` in Python 3.9:

```
class _ProtocolMeta(ABCMeta):
    # This metaclass is really unfortunate and exists only because of
    # the lack of __instancehook__.
    def __instancecheck__(cls, instance):
        # We need this method for situations where attributes are
        # assigned in __init__.
        if ((not getattr(cls, '_is_protocol', False) or
                _is_callable_members_only(cls)) and
                issubclass(instance.__class__, cls)):
            return True
        if cls._is_protocol:
            if all(hasattr(instance, attr) and
                    # All *methods* can be blocked by setting them to None.
                    (not callable(getattr(cls, attr, None)) or
                     getattr(instance, attr) is not None)
                    for attr in _get_protocol_attrs(cls)):
                return True
        return super().__instancecheck__(instance)
```

As indicated by the first comment, the only purpose of the class is to provide an `__instancecheck__` hook for `isinstance(instance, cls)` with `cls` being a subclass of `typing.Protocol`. Furthermore, in `Protocol.__init_subclass__`, a class subclassing from `Protocol` gets the attribute `_is_protocol` set to `True` if any of its bases is `Protocol`, in other words, if the class is a Protocol in sense of [PEP 544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/#defining-a-protocol).

I understand that checking an object to be an instance of a Protocol requires a special treatmeant, since [PEP 544 states](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/#subtyping-relationships-with-other-types):

> A concrete type X is a subtype of protocol P if and only if X
> implements all protocol members of P with compatible types. In other
> words, subtyping with respect to a protocol is always structural.

But I cannot recognize this special treatment in the implementation given by the source code above. Moreover, I cannot figure out any reasonable rationale for the implementation above. Can somebody explain it, please?

Especially, I don't understand the condition `getattr(instance, attr) is not None` in the [line 1110](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/typing.py#L1110):
Why it is needed to check if a protocol attribute (assured to exist on the instance: `hasattr(instance, attr)`) is not `None` on the instance if this attribute is callable in the protocol? If to check for a value, then I would think of checking for being callable, not just for just `None`.